# How to use regular expression and matches to search multiple search terms in multiple fields?

Tags: .net, regex

I have an Person object array.I want to search multiple search terms in multiple fields.I succeded to search multiple searchterm into one field.But I dont know how to overcome to search multiple search terms in multiple fields.what I tried is as follows.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"(daniels|john|jack|freeman)"); //multiple search terms

var queryMatchingFiles =
    from a in list
    let matches = searchTerm.Matches(a.Name)
    //let matches = searchTerm.Matches(a.Surname) it gives an error
    where matches.Count > 0
    select new
    {
        a
    };

 ...

class Person
 {
     private string name;
     private string surname;
     private string tc;

     public Person(string name, string surname, string tc)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.surname = surname;
         this.tc = tc;
     }

     public string Name
     {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; }
     }

     public string Surname
     {
         get { return surname; }
         set { surname = value; }
     }

     public string Tc
     {
         get { return tc; }
         set { tc = value; }
     }
 }
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you need to return `a` only when the search term is found in *any* of the fields? Try `where (searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Name) || searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Surname))`

Comment: Yes the object/s found must return to show the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.IsMatch` to check if a regex pattern matches a given field and use OR logical operator to make sure the `a` is returned if *any* of the fields match:

```
var list = new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "daniels", Surname ="koln" },
           new Person { Name = "jon", Surname ="freeman" }};
var searchTerm = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(daniels|john|jack|freeman)");
var queryMatchingFiles =
      (from a in list
       where (searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Name) || searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Surname)) // Add conditions here
       select new
       {
          a
       }).ToList();
```

[image]

As per your edit, use

```
where (searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Name) || 
       searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Surname) ||
       searchTerm.IsMatch(a.Tc))
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).